# Unable to turn off error messages using Parallelize

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

I am running 11.1 and would like to run NIntegrate and turn off the error message NIntegrate::ncvb but when I run the integrations in parallel, they are not being turned off.  For example, consider the following which turns off Log::argt: 
 I can successfully turn it off if I run it directly:

```
Off[Log::argt]
Table[Log[n, b, c], {n, 1, 10}]
```

but if I use Parallelize:

```
Off[Log::argt]
Parallelize[Table[Log[n, b, c], {n, 1, 10}]]
```

Each of my two kernels still prints the error messages.  And this is still the case if I use

```
Quiet[Parallelize[Table[Log[n, b, c], {n, 1, 
  10}]]]
```

I was wondering if there is a way to turn off the error messages in the Kernels as they clutter up my output when I parallelize a large number of integrations.

Comment: `ParallelEvaluate@Off[Log::argt]`